# SurveyForce 'X-Frame-Options issues in Communities

Tags: apex, community, profile, security, iframe

We are trying to use SurveyForce for communities (Visualforce + Tabs), but I am having trouble with iFrames.

For a System Admin, when he logs into the Community, it works perfectly fine. Preview in the iframe gets displayed properly.

For a Salesforce license, custom profile (for Community Administrator), I am getting the following error in Chrome console

```
Refused to display 'https://******.force.com/login?ec=302&inst=35&startURL=%2Fapex%2Ftakesurvey%3Fid%3Da5l3500000000t4AAA%26cId%3Dnone%26caId%3Dnone' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

In the Site Details, I have set

```
Clickjack Protection Level to Allow framing by any page (no protection)
```

In Session Settings > Clickjack Protection

```
FALSE (unchecked) for Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages with standard headers

FALSE (unchecked) for Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages with headers disabled
```

For the user with Community Admin profile, I also tried to go to Surveys from the Org Internal portal, and access Surveys. The Preview (iFrame) gets displayed.

Based on that, I am assuming the entire issue is with the Community. 
I am looking for some clues to solve this issue. Unable to troubleshoot the issue so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gkolan,

You would need to add the community specific site prefix to the rendered frames within SurveyForce code (vf/apex).

Hope this helps someone who also lands on to same issues.